# Spark : How do I put the grouped DataSet<Row> into the right KAFKA topics

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-dataset

I have a nested `JSON`, which I have read as `DataSet<Row>` into spark.
I have grouped them on various columns also. 
My requirement is to group `JSON` and put them into the right Kafka topics.
I am not knowing how to map `DataSet<Row>` which contains grouped records for various Kafka topics.
For example:
My JSON is

```
{
"entity": {
    "name": "SJ",
    "id": 31
},
"hierarchy": {
    "state": "TN",
    "city": "CBE"
},
"data": {}}
```

So I have to group by the hierarchy key. I have achieved this.
This is the code.

```
public void jsonGroup() {
    Dataset<Row> studentRecordDS = spark.read()
            .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
            .json("/home/shiney/Documents/NGA/sparkJsonFiles/Original/*.json");
    StructType st = studentRecordDS.schema();
    Dataset<Row> resultSet = studentRecordDS.select("*").groupBy("hie","dim").count();
    resultSet.show();
    Dataset<Row> joinedDS = studentRecordDS.join(resultSet,"hie");
}
```

How do I convert map the rows inside the Dataset to it appropriate Kafka topics?

For example, if there are three json records, rec1: state "TN", rec2: state "TN" and rec3: state "MH". So my records will be grouped like    "TN" -> rec1,rec2 and "MH"-> rec3.So my Kafka topics will be TN and MH. and rec1 and rec2 should go to TN and rec3 should be put in MH.

Comment: you mean all hie in topic1 and dim in topic 2 like that?

Comment: No. For example if there are three records, rec 1 : state "TN", rec2: state "TN" and rec3 : state "MH". So my records will be grouped like "TN" -> rec1, rec2 and  "MH" -> rec3. So my kafka topics will be TN and MH. and rec1 and rec2 should go to TN and rec3 should be put in MH. Adding the same comment as edit to my question.